# Error: Cannot find module 'hbsfy'

Tags: linux, server, gulp

Issue with Script

Hello i will install https://github.com/cloverstudio/Spika/tree/master/web/src/server

I become on :

```
gulp build-dist

Error: Cannot find module 'hbsfy'
```

I Hope this is all what i need for installing this the Tutorial is not the best from the website :)

How can i fix the issue with this? What for Module is needet?

Comment: Example ( from Google, hbsfy ) https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbsfy-global → " Install hbsfy locally to your project: `npm install hbsfy` "

Comment: not working for me same issue

Comment: I had same issues, I ran
npm install hbsfy
npm install handlebars
npm install jsdoc
But still this is not enough, jsdoc is not enough to go forward...

Answer (score 0):

I faced same and more issues too. I'm trying Spika on Ubuntu 16.04 Server. 
Before `$ npm install` it was necessary `$ sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

Answering to your questiong, first of all just on web directory clean all npm

```
rm -rf node_modules/
```

Now we can run the following commands:

```
npm install
npm install gulp-util
npm install minimatch
npm install graceful-fs
npm install gulp -g
npm install hbsfy
npm install handlebars
```

This is not enough because jsdoc is not as expected. All the files and directories inside node_modules/jsdoc/lib/jsdoc should be inside node_modules/jsdoc so just create a symbolic link for each of them

e.g.

```
cd node_modules/jsdoc
ln -sf lib/jsdoc/opts opts
ln -sf lib/jsdoc/util util
etc... etc...
```

Now we can finally run

```
gulp build-dist
```

Hope you find it usefull, regards ;)